# Reusable code for classes

Tags: ios, swift, oop

Several classes in my app do the same thing and have the same instance variables:

```
// one of the many classes I have
// they all load nibs and update the frames of their views
class HelpView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HelpView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
        self.view.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

I want to avoid duplicated code, so I thought about using a superclass so that all the classes inherit from it.

```
// my new superclass all classes will inherit from
class ReusableView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView! // all subclasses have different views

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        // every class has a different nib name
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Nib name goes here", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.view)
        self.view.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

The problem is that `view` is `nil` until the nib is loaded, so it's apparently not possible to call that superclass' method because you're passing a nil object. How can I handle this?

Comment: Create a shared utility class. Write a function there and pass the nibName(string), viewController'view as parameter. Call this method when you need. In this way you can remove the duplicacy of code.

Comment: Add abstract view and name properties to the base class.  The method uses these properties. The derived classes implement them with their unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
class ReusableView: UIView {

    func getHelperView() -> UIView! {
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overridden") 
    } 

    func getNibName() -> String {
        preconditionFailure("This method must be overridden") 
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

        // every class has a different nib name
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(self.getNibName(), owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.getHelperView())
        self.getHelperView().frame = self.bounds
    }
}

class HelpView: ReusableView {
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!

    override func getHelperView() -> UIView! {
         return view;
    } 

    override func getNibName() -> String {
         return "NibName";
    } 
}
```